# My output is coming up as _ when I run tests in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Okay so I have multiple test cases setup, and then their grouped together at the end.
**I forgot to put some of the code up, so I added it**

The problem is when I put for example **Main>tests 1**  the correct answer is displayed but if I try to run the test cases individually such as **main>test0** my output becomes "TestCase _ "

or **main>Alltests** my out put is " TestList [TestLabel test1 TestCase _,TestLabel test0 TestCase _,TestLabel test7 TestCase _,TestLabel est51 TestCase _] "

My question is what causes the _ and why isn't it recognizing the test cases

```
assertException :: (Exception e, Eq e) => e -> IO a -> IO ()
assertException ex action =
      handleJust isWanted (const $ return ()) $ do
            action
            assertFailure $ "Expected exception: " ++ show ex
     where isWanted = guard . (== ex) 

assertError ex f = 
      assertException (ErrorCall ex) $ evaluate f



tests :: Integer -> [Integer]

tests n | n == 0              = error "Not positive"
        | n == 1              = [1]
        | (n `div` 2 == 0)    = n:tests(n*2)
        | otherwise           = n:tests(3*n) 



test0 = 
      TestCase ( assertError
                    "tests 0" 
                     ( tests 0 )
               )


test7 = 
      TestCase ( assertEqual
                    "tests 7" 
                [7,18,9]
                     ( tests 7 )
                )

test51 = 
      TestCase ( assertEqual
                    [9,8,9]
                    "tests 51"

                  ( tests 51 )
               )



alltests = 
     TestList [
             -- TestLabel "test1" test1
               TestLabel "test0" test0
             , TestLabel "test7" test7
             , TestLabel "test51"test51
             ]
```

Comment: "Disregard some of the spacing when I copied here it didn't come out right" <- that's a bad sign. Did you use tabs in your source? If so, don't. With tabs, code that looks indented correctly can be totally mucked up.

Comment: The test case spacing is correct in my program, the test cases were given as a template where I had to write the code in place. My code is just not cooperating with the test cases it's like it's not recognizing the ex: ( tests 51 ) part in the test cases

Comment: That was just a general advice. If your indentation had been actually broken by tabs, you would have gotten an error message.

Comment: @DanielFischer This is one of my pet peeves (on the #haskell IRC channel, too). "Don't use tabs" is pithy, but too conservative. Tabs are a very useful tool when used correctly.

Comment: FWIW, Do you really mean ``n `div` 2 == 0``?  That's only true when `n` is 0 or 1, which are cases you have already covered.  Perhaps you meant `mod`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I have to say that your code is a mess. You did write that the copying ruined your formatting, but still, if you really want a well-written solution to your problem, it would be nice to also write a well-written question. 
Nevertheless, there are several changes necessary to actually run your code.

For example:
In your definition of `test0`, you use a function called `assertError` that does not exist, so I assume, you mean `assertEqual` like in your other test cases. The other problem with your test cases is the *usage* of the function `assertEqual :: (Eq a, Show a) => String -> a -> a -> Assertion`: it takes three arguments, but in your definition it only gets two. The latter two argument represent the expected and the actual value, I guess, you forgot the actual value. So I don't know, what you want to test.

Edit: But I guess that the problem with your function and corresponding tests are, that your function constructs an infinite list (except for `0` or `1` as input value for `n`), so your function does not terminate as well as the test cases. (I first thought that this is also the reason for the cryptic output, but this seems to be wrong.)

Answer (score 6):

You don't actually run the tests when you type `test0` or `allTests` (note: that cannot start with an upper case letter, since it's not a constructor) at the prompt. `test0` is a value of type [`Test`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HUnit/1.2.5.1/doc/html/Test-HUnit-Base.html#t%3aTest) and `allTests` too. So when you type either of these at the ghci prompt, that value is converted to a `String` via `show`, and that `String` is then printed out.

The `Show` instance for [`Test`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HUnit/1.2.5.1/doc/html/Test-HUnit-Base.html#t%3aTest) cannot convert the contained [`Assertion`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HUnit/1.2.5.1/doc/html/Test-HUnit-Base.html#t%3aAssertion)s to a meaningful `String` because an `Assertion` is an `IO`-action. Thus it generically displays an underscore there to indicate "here is an assertion".

```
tests 1
```

on the other hand is an expression of type `tests 1 :: Integral a => [a]`, and when you type such an expression at the prompt, that is too converted to a `String` via `show` (after fixing the type variable `a` by defaulting to `Integer`), but here the `Show` instance requires the list to be completely evaluated.

To actually run your tests, you need [`runTestTT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HUnit/1.2.5.1/doc/html/Test-HUnit-Text.html#v%3arunTestTT) or [`performTest`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HUnit/1.2.5.1/doc/html/Test-HUnit-Base.html#v%3aperformTest) (or one of the other test-runners from HUnit).